# Remove an element from session using symfony2 and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a question, So I tried to remove an element from session using ajax.
My route is :

```
shoppingCart_delete:
path: /cartItems/delete/{id}
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:Basket:delete }
requirements:
    id:  \d+
    _method:  POST
```

My fonction delete :

```
public function deleteAction($id){
    $sessionVal = $this->get( 'session' )->get( 'aBasket' );
    unset($sessionVal[$id]);
}
```

My ajax code :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function removeItemFromSession(id){
        console.log(id);
        var id = id,
        url_deploy = "http://"+window.location.hostname+":1234"+"/cartItems/delete";
        console.log(url_deploy);
        $.ajax({
            url: url_deploy,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: { id:id},
            success : function(data){
                document.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function(){
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And my html :

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeItemFromSession({{ product['product_id'] }})" title="Remove this item">Remove</a>
```

I get in console the error :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://shop.com:1234/cartItems/delete"
```

Can you help me please? Thx in advance!!

Comment: what happens when you directly try to access http://shop.com:1234/cartItems/delete URL ?

Comment: I get an 404 : No route found for "GET /cartItems/delete"

Comment: that's expected, because you have defined path up to "/cartItems/delete/{id}" and not just to "/cartItems/delete". Try accessing "/cartItems/delete/1" and I am sure your deleteAction function will be executed. Here "1" can be any id.

Comment: You have specified POST method in ajax. Try by using GET method so that your url will be matched with defined route file. And parameter id will be passed as url parameter

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to do following changes :

```
1. From path: /cartItems/delete/{id} to path: /cartItems/delete
2. public function deleteAction($id){ to 
 public function deleteAction(Request $request){
  if ($id = $request->request->get('id', false)) {
       ...........
  }
}
```

In short, we are omitting "id" key from the URL and accessing it via "Request".

Comment: Now I get : 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: that's different issue. Try just echo some text within the function and see if that works. Also you need to "use" SF's request class before your controller class begins. 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;